# Measuring capacitance of two wires

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, calibration, capacity, calculate

I have made a capacitor as follows:

I cut two straight wires of diameter 0.52 mm and length of 29 cm and separation width of s=2.5 cm.

I stuck them on a piece of neon to keep them fixed.

Here is the formula of the overall capacitance:

[image]

[Here is the link that I use to calculate.](https://www.emisoftware.com/calculator/wire-pair-capacitance/)

That gives me capacitance on the order of picofarads ->e^-12F.

In my experiments it looks like the overall capacitance is of nanofarad order.

Here is why I think so:

I generated a 100 kHz square wave and tried to pass it through this DIY capacitor and a resistor (which gives me a low pass filter.) I noticed that in order to see double exponential sawtooth, the value of resistor should be around 5.6 kohm.

Consequently I concluded that for tau (1/RC) of 5 us (for 100 kHz square wave,) C should be of nanofarad order.

Why there is so much difference between the theoretical calculations and the value calculated in experiments?

Comment: what is a piece of neon?

Comment: How are you measuring it? Show your setup.

Comment: Neon is a gas.  It is hard to stick things to a gas.  I know that in Germany, fluorescent lights are known as "neon" lights despite there not being any neon in them.  Did you mean a piece of glass tube from a fluorescent light tube?

Answer (score 3):

> *I noticed that in order to see double exponential sawtooth....*

To see that waveform presumably you used an oscilloscope. Did you check what the input capacitance of the scope probe is (maybe around 10 to 22 pF) and did you realize that it will need to be factored in when making this experiment.

Comment: seems logical. No, I didn't take the oscilloscope's capacitance into count. So, how do you think should I measure and monitor the results?

Answer (score 0):

By inspection the calculated order of pF value seems reasonable. 1m of coaxial cable has a typical capacitance of ~100pF. That is longer, has a smaller gap and much larger electrode area than your setup. *Each* one of these factor increases the capacitance over your situation but results in much less than nF values. So this is not a theory/practice issue, there is something wrong with the measurement.

If you remove the capacitor from the setup what does Tau change to? Is this a signal generator or oscilloscope issue? Both must have risetimes much shorter than 5us. Yes the comment on scope input C is valid but it wont cause nF level measurements. If you measured 20pF then I'd suspect this to be the issue.

Also your numbers are a little suspicious. Normally one would use a frequency low enough such that a high or low period is maybe 5 Tau so the exponential can settle and the final value be estimated. At 100k the half period is 5us so the final value can't be determined so how can you work out when 0.63 of final has been reached? Its not impossible but I wonder if you have made a mistake here.

Such  measurement really needs a low input C buffer amp to be placed right near the RC network. 10cm of coax will add 10pF which is alot bigger than what you are trying to measure.

In short measuring pF level values is very hard and many things matter.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring a 1 pF cap is certainly possible, but technique becomes important. Basically, you are treating your setup as if only the cap is affecting the reading. And that is not remotely true at 1 pF levels.

Try something like this. Make an RC circuit using you generator, resistor, oscilloscope and a store-bought 1 pF capacitor (Digikey or Mouser are good sources). Make the setup so that the overall length of the cap is 2.5 cm. Run your measurements. Now do it again, but this time adding another 1 pf cap. Now remove the 2nd cap, and hook up to your wire cap.

Compare the 3 readings. I'm pretty sure (without bothering to second-guess your calculations) that your original reading was caused by various stray capacitances, including your scope. Your second and third readings represent the difference between your setup capacitances and an added cap.

Depending on other stray values, and exactly how you are interpreting your scope traces, you may also be seeing effects from the inductance in that 29 cm pair of wires.

But do keep in mind that your 1 pF caps will have a very large tolerance (typically 0.5 pF) so this isn't a precision measurement. For that you'll need to learn about AC bridges or grid dip meters, and learn a LOT more about working with very small capacitances.

Good luck.